# Codeigniter 2.1.4 application got hacked?

Tags: php, security, codeigniter-2

A strange thing occurred today. I have made a CI based site, and a hacker managed to:

1. Overwrite my *index.php* file by making a file upload to root;
2. Inject code direct into my *index.php* replacing everything with a dummy html formatted page;

I don't know which of the above actual occurred.

The site is quite simple (no input forms, no db ecc.), I started developing it with CodeIgniter since client didn't know what he wanted, so I ended up using the framework just for templating and compressing.

I have strong doubts whether a security hole was offered to the hacker on the PHP side. I am incline to believe the issue is from my hosting service bad server configuration (I had a bad chat with them, they say they will look into it)

I find it very curious that only the index.php was (***apparently***) modified (application and system are also in the root since I do not have FTP access above, maybe if I were an hacker I would have deleted any file in root before allowing my fancy index to showy perform)

How did this happen? What do you think is most likely possible?

Comment: your guess is as good as ours, check in with your hosting provider, looks like it is access to the server vs ci compromise which would most likely happen with injection or other attacks. Maybe your directory permissions were `777`?

Comment: @Jakub I have 755 for directories and 644 for files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no one will give you a straight answer without full access to the server, the server and system logs etc. It could be one of many things, if you are on a shared hosting, simply bad configuration of the server will often mean enough (meaning if a person compromises one site, he compromised them all). It could be outdated services on the server, where the attacker used a publicly available exploit. It also might be CI based exploit, private or public...

Chances are, if you are confident that your website couldn't have been hacked, it will most likely be a badly configured shared hosting environment and permissions, allowing the attacker to access system commands and folders that don't belong to the user, which often would've been followed by uploading a php shell via a vulnerable site and from there it would be as simple as browsing folders of a web server. 
Second likely I would say is that it could have been outdated exploitable service running on the shared host.

If there is any "signature" in the html you were talking about, you might want to try to google it and see what returns. Also you might want to try to execute some system commands via PHP (something you shouldn't be able to access like `ls` level below your web root; if you are able, it is likely the attacker access your files that way.

Comment: I uploaded a test.php on my root containing: exec('ls', $array) and printed the Array ( [0] => application [1] => sylesheet [2] => images [3] => index.php [4] => js [5] => system [6] => test.php )

Comment: well that for one means that you are able to execute commands, which is normally bad enough on a shared host, because one slip up with permissions means the whole server is at risk. As said in my previous post, try to `ls -l ../` in the your web root, if you don't get an error, I would say it's fairly certain that is how the attacker compromised your website. Also check the ownership of the files, if it's something generic (like if all your files belong to apache user), you are likely to have another issue, because anyone who executes a command via php will be able to access those files

Comment: changing to `ls -l ../` I can see all the server directories indeed -_-' ownership seems good

Comment: well there you go. you could try to inform your host, however from my experience they will refuse to even acknowledge it, tell you to tweak your file permissions, and leave it as it is. So I would say your best option after that would be to change the host to something more reliable and secure (I would give you a recommendation, but honestly for a few years I've managed my own servers and VPSs, so I couldn't reliably say)

Comment: Thank you! You really helped me a lot. This entire attack experience was helpful. It made me dig for information opening my eyes to attacking thecniques I was ignoring.

Comment: No bother, glad I could help.